# Amazon EC2 server cannot connect and access via putty out of sudden

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty, amazon-ec2

I have a ubuntu server setup in amazon ec2 for few months. Today, out of sudden, the server status is not reacheable and putty is not accessible too.

I've also rebooted the system, it seems to be not able to connect via putty too. (Note, there is no server config  changes / installation during the outage.)

After many tries, i decided to cloned the image, then it is up again.  May I know anyone out there is facing such problem on amazon ec2 before?

I would like to find out the root cause of why it is suddenly unreachable as this is production server and critical to us.

Answer (score 1):

The basic check for any EC2 outages is to use the AWS console/dashboard - it will show if there are any fundamental issues at the minute for the region you are using.

That said, usually access connection issues for AWS are due to a VPC ACL or Security Group specifying a set of IP addresses where your IP is no longer one of the IP addresses listed.

It's possible your ISP has changed your IP address on you - I would recommend going into the AWS console and checking if there is a list (usually in a Security Group) and then checking if your current IP is one of the allowed IPs - you can use sites such as http://www.whatismyip.com/ or in the Security Group console add a new rule and choose the 'my current IP' option to check.

On a side note, if you don't have a list of IP addresses either via an ACL or a Security Group, then you really should implement such a filter - otherwise you are opening up an administrative port out to the internet, can that can cause all sorts of 'fun' that you may not desire.